# Configuring xDebug behind a NAT on a VM

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm, nat, vmware-player

I'm setting up a development environment in a VM Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware Player. The host system is a windows 7 machine that I developed on previously. The project itself is mounted on a remote samba share, and the web application is run on a remote server. I've never had any problems using phpStorm's debugger in Win 7.

I've gone through identical configurations in phpStorm, and I've set both of them to break on the first line of the script.

I can't change the php.ini settings on the target server, and I've set up proper path mappings to the network drive.

I suspect this is an issue involving the NAT/firewall configuration of the VM, but I don't know where to look. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: 1) xdebug just needs an IP of the machine where PhpStorm is running -- as seen **from that VM machine**. You can check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or similar for such IP. That IP should not change (AFAIK). Alternatively you can try `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` option in your php.ini ( http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back ) so xdebug will **automatically** attempt to debug **every single request**.

Comment: 2) Do not forget to setup correct path mappings in `Settings | PHP | Servers` so that IDE knows how to translate remote paths into local

Comment: useful links: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide  **2)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: I should note, I cannot edit php.ini on the remote program I'm debugging against.

Comment: If you can not edit php.ini on the server that runs your PHP app, how are you going to turn on debugging in the first place?

Comment: It's enabled on on the server.I can debug in phpStorm on my windows 7 host enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that with VMware, network bridging has to be enabled, after I configured that, it worked fine.